# ACR122U Not connect

Tags: python, nfc

My ACR122U had connected to my device but the code said there is no device.
Code:

```
import nfc
def on_connect(tag):
    url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1IMc-Gv6vdNLO5j7AUPgVz9lyq77O6w9v"
    ndef_message = nfc.ndef.Message([
        nfc.ndef.UriRecord(url)
    ])
    tag.ndef.message = ndef_message

    print(f"URL '{url}' written to the NFC tag")
clf = nfc.ContactlessFrontend()
try:
    print("Hold an NFC tag near the reader to write the URL...")
    clf.connect(rdwr={'on-connect': on_connect})
finally:
    clf.close()
```

Output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\giang\OneDrive\Desktop\coding\python\Untitled-1.py", line 14, in 
clf.connect(rdwr={'on-connect': on_connect})
File "C:\Users\giang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\nfc\clf_*init*_.py", line 496, in connect
raise IOError(errno.ENODEV, os.strerror(errno.ENODEV))
OSError: [Errno 19] No such device

evidence:

[This show ACR122U had connected to my device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icQJA.png)

I need help on fixing this problem.